# insert custom changelog to Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, changelog

Is it possible to insert a changelog.xml file to Jenkins build jobs? I create a file (the right style and syntax) an copy it to *Jenkins/job/jobname/build/lastSuccessfullBuild* but if I click on *changes* on the job overview there are still *no changes*. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I just found out, that the initialisation of the Changelog happens inside the SCM step. I use clone workspace to get the workspace for my build job. So I replaced the changelog.xml of my getWorkspace job. Now the changelog.xml of inside my build job is the modified file but the *Changes* Button still shows *no changes*

Comment: have you tried to update changelog.xml file in [jobname]/builds/[buildnumber]?

Comment: Yes I replaced the xml file but this dont work

Comment: I added an **EDIT** with some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by performing an *getprojectdiff | tmp.xml* call from my integrity repo. Afterwards I transform this xml via xsl to html to publish it via sidebar links inside my project.